# Google Maps Info Cards With Events?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I am currently working on a project for new homes throughout neighborhoods in Indiana.  I'm using Google Fusion tables to populate the map on my site.
We want to be able to force users to sign in after they click the "builder site" link on the info card (the pop up from the google location marker).  Is there a way to add events to the google info cards?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with stock Fusion Tables info windows because we scrub any JavaScript in them. You can code this up yourself if you want; see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12041805/suppress-fusion-table-infowindow-with-multiple-layers) for an example.

A cleaner way might be to process all the links on your own HTTP server, showing the login page if necessary or redirecting to the builder site if not. That would work with no custom client code, but would require the appropriate server-side setup.